# Как написать приложение библиотеку?

Tags: c++, мобильная-разработка

Мне нужно написать приложение библиотеку, а именно в приложении должны хранится файлы, ну а пользователь будет искать нужный ему файл

Как это реализовать на языке программирования С++?

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно из вашего вопроса что вам нужно - полноценная файловая система, либо же модель пользователь закинул файл -> можно по ним вести поиск. Графический интерфейс можно сделать через Qt, его я вам и рекомендую. Все остальное, что связано с работой с файлами можно нагуглить. Это что касается приложений для десктопа. Исходя из вашего тега к вопросу <мобильная разработка> могу предложить Android NDK, но, как мне кажется, для вашей задачи  больше подойдет Java или Kotlin, нежели делать именно такое приложение на C++

Comment: На кьюте можно спокойно сделать, не надо советовать джаву/котлин и тд)

Comment: @ГлебТруфанов вы правы, из головы вылетело, что он кроссплатформенный

Answer (score 0):

Что-то типа проводника в винде? Твой вопрос задан крайне обширно и некорректно, поэтому уже поставили минус. Старайся более явно формулировать вопрос и цель твоих задачи.

В любом случае, если тебе нужно какое-то гуишное приложение, в котором можно красиво работать с файлами, то просто скачай [Qt](https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer?hsCtaTracking=99d9dd4f-5681-48d2-b096-470725510d34%7C074ddad0-fdef-4e53-8aa8-5e8a876d6ab4) и глянь документацию класса [QFile](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) и [модель-представление](http://itnotesblog.ru/note.php?id=159), чтоб красиво файлы выводить в виде всяких таблиц и т.д.

На твой вопрос в данном виде лучше тебе никто не ответит)